# ElasticSearch Regexp query over multiple terms

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I want users to be able to do regex search that spans over multiple terms, however the regexp query only searches within terms. I have tried to do `"index":    "not_analyzed"` but the problem is that I'm indexing entire files and they are too long to fit in the ElasticSearch limit for a single term (32766). I can't split it up because that breaks the regex (which is the problem). I either need a way to be able to search across multiple terms, or a way to index larger than 32766 files.

Comment: Searching by regex in multiple terms would defeat the purpose of an inverted index. Maybe you should provide some other alternative to your users. What kind of queries do they need to do?

Comment: For example if i wanted to find everywhere that the word `find` is somewhere between `(` and `)` so `(hey there find me)` How could i do that without regex?

Comment: This totally depends on what the analyzer does with punctuation. The default one just strips it. You'd first have to use a suitable analyzer for this task, then supposing that the parentheses are separate tokens, I think you could build something with a [span near query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-span-near-query.html).

Comment: That was just an example. If i wanted to find something between the words `one` and `two` like `one person should do this and two`...These are arbitrary length's as well so a span near with slop isn't necessarily the best either.